# VS Code find widget updates as I type instead of waiting for me to press enter

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is an annoyance that I am struggling with and can't seem to find the proper keywords to search for a solution.

When you have an open editor using VS Code, you can press Ctrl+F to bring up the search bar which searches inside the currently open file.

However, this search has this most annoying behavior that insists on searching for whatever character you type in, as you are typing, instead of waiting for you to press the enter key like it does in the "Search all files" tab!

Is there a way to change this behavior? If not, any tips to circumvent this issue?

Comment: well, https://code.visualstudio.com/community says to "ask a question" here. Will go there too, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right side of the search bar are some icons for certain search options. Try selecting 'Match Whole Word'. The search will only look for the character string you type in. This is not a perfect fix but sure helps.  I just tried it on character string popt and nothing happened until i typed in the whole string.

Comment: Doesn't really fix it, but does help. Thanks.